# How do I execute an coco2d game that is within my current iOS application?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have recently created a cocos2d app, and I need to be to launch
the application via a UIButton in my main XIB. I have currently added the cocos-2d-ios.xcodeproj and MyGame.xcodeproj into my app. All projects build successfully until I try to import a cocos2d header onto my main View Controller I get one of the errors.

22:10: 'cassert' file not found

Is there a way that I can do this? Is it possible?

Thank You.

Comment: Compile as Objective-C++, perhaps? This is not related to Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread discusses the same issue.-

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21853

It seems that renaming your .m classes to .mm may fix the problem.

Comment: that's all I had to do. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked :) By the way, if you think this is the right answer, please, consider marking it as right.